# Not consuming Keybord event for window button JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am not able to consume keyboard events for WINDOWS,Esc in my JavaFx application

```
if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.WINDOWS) {
    System.out.print("\n\n window");
    keyEvent.consume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think may be you are using wrong EventHandler. Try this event filter handler it works properly with consume() method.

```
txtBox.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
    {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) 
    {
    if(event.getCode()==KeyCode.ESCAPE)
             event.consume();                                    
    }});
```